# Puzzling Chinese conversations

Tags: word, pronunciation, learning

**Puzzle 1:**

A: 張先生還在人事部上班嗎? - Does Mr. Zhang still work for HR?

B: 不在, 昨天**上調**了. - No, he was promoted and moved to somewhere else yesterday.

A: 啊, 他死啦!? 我前天還見到他, 怎麼這麼快就走了呢? Ah, he was dead?! I have only seen him the day before, how could he pass away so quickly?

B: #!%$*@???

**Q:** Why B was surprised by A's response?

**Puzzle 2:**

Young lady: 小王**吧**, 你好? - Little Wang, howdy?

Young man: 第一次見面, 怎麼罵人呢! - Why curse me on the first date!

**Q:** What did the young lady say to the young man that got such a response?

Comment: Homophone Puzzles are a good way to learn a language, and contextual recognition. Any more?, as it is useful and fun for new learners.

Comment: You can make a joke out of the first sentence by dropping a few words :)

Answer (score 5):

For your first puzzle, the word 上調 sounds the same as 上吊, which means hanged himself. That is why A is asking if he died. And because B means he got promoted, B is surprised by A's response.

The second puzzle is in the same fashion. 小王吧 sounds exactly like 小王八, which means little turtle, a less literal translation would be little motherf*cker.